# Spring boot camel saga implementation using LRA coordinator giving back connection refused

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, saga, narayana

I am trying to implement Apache Camel Saga EPI for my Spring Boot app, with usage of external LRA coordinator (using  [Narayana](https://stackoverflow.com) in docker ).
Although I am able to verify that LRA coordinator is working at specified port, when the application attempt to use it no completion / compensation actions happens. Rest of the route runs.
Trying to debug the LRA coordinator the logger shows

> LRAParticipantRecord.doEnd(complete) HTTP PUT at http://localhost:8081/api/lra-participant/complete?Camel-Saga-Compensate=direct://sagaCompensated&Camel-Saga-Complete=direct://sagaCompleted failed for LRA http://localhost:8080/lra-coordinator/0_ffffac110002_88d3_64e47db5_2 (reason: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081)

With the details below it should be possible to test demo app.
Any help is appreciated :)

Here are my settings
app.properties for camel.lra.*

```
server:
  port: 8081

camel:
  service:
    lra:
      enabled: true
  lra:
    enabled: true
    coordinator-url: http://localhost:8080
    coordinator-context-path: /lra-coordinator
    local-participant-url: http://localhost:8081/api
    local-participant-context-path: /lra-participant
  servlet:
    mapping:
      enabled: true
      context-path: /api/*
```

docker cmd

```
docker run -it --rm -e LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG -p 8080:8080 quay.io/jbosstm/lra-coordinator
```

I also did try to run

```
docker run --network host quay.io/jbosstm/lra-coordinator:latest
```

but without success

Here is my camel route

```
 @Component
public class SagaRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet")
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
        
        rest("/hello").post()
        .to("direct:hello");

        from("direct:hello")
        .log("The body is ${body}!")
        .transform().simple("Hello World");
        
        rest().post("/saga")
        .type(Order.class)
            .to("direct:saga");
        
        from("direct:saga")
        .log("saga starting...")
            .saga()
                .to("direct:serviceOne")
                .to("direct:serviceTwo")
            .completion("direct:sagaCompleted")
            .compensation("direct:sagaCompensated")
            .to("direct:completed")
        .end();
    
        from("direct:serviceOne")
        .process(new GenerateIdempotencyIdProcessor())
            .saga()
            .propagation(SagaPropagation.SUPPORTS)
            .option("body", body())
            .compensation("direct:serviceOneCancel")
            .bean(ServiceOne.class, "performOperation");
    
        from("direct:serviceOneCancel")
            .routeId("service-one-cancel")
            .log("Canceling one")
            .transform(header("body"))
            .bean(ServiceOne.class, "cancelOperation");
    
        from("direct:serviceTwo")
            .saga()
            .propagation(SagaPropagation.SUPPORTS)
            .option("body", body())
            .compensation("direct:serviceTwoCancel")
            .bean(ServiceTwo.class, "performOperation");
    
        from("direct:serviceTwoCancel")
            .routeId("service-two-cancel")
            .log("Canceling two")
            .transform(header("body"))
            .bean(ServiceTwo.class, "cancelOperation");
    
        from("direct:sagaCompleted")
            .routeId("saga-completion-route")
            .log("Saga Completed");
    
        from("direct:sagaCompensated")
            .routeId("saga-compensation-route")
            .log("Saga Compensating...");
        
        from("direct:completed")
            .setBody(constant("Completed bro"));
    }
    
}
```

and here is the log of the app once the saga is completed, I am missing the completion action from the saga. Same goes for compensation (*below the saga completed log is missing*)

> 2023-08-22 12:16:16.734  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] route4                                   : saga starting...
> 2023-08-22 12:16:16.812  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.services.ServiceOne                  : serviceOne --> incoming exchange --> request payload --> Order(...order details...)
>
> 2023-08-22 12:16:16.813  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.services.ServiceOne                  : serviceOne --> incoming exchange --> LRA ID --> http://localhost:8080/lra-coordinator/0_ffffac110002_88d3_64e47db5_2
> 2023-08-22 12:16:17.698  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.services.ServiceOne                  : Operation performed from ServiceOne: ServiceOne~f63e9123-cb7e-477d-9956-5f77224922a6
> 2023-08-22 12:16:17.769  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.services.ServiceTwo                  : serviceTwo --> incoming exchange --> request payload --> Order(...order details....)
> 2023-08-22 12:16:17.770  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.services.ServiceTwo                  : serviceTwo --> incoming exchange --> LRA ID --> http://localhost:8080/lra-coordinator/0_ffffac110002_88d3_64e47db5_2
> 2023-08-22 12:16:18.763  INFO 6416 --- [onPool-worker-1] c.c.services.ServiceTwo                  : Operation performed from ServiceTwo: ServiceTwo~8587d7c3-2ce7-46fe-8d1b-88b3511d9e01